# Preventing errors in index format when deleting rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a worksheet where I developed a calendar that populates based on the date in the calendar, referencing an array on the sheet to find matches. This is the code I'm using for it

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($AD$1:$AE$705,SMALL(IF($AD$1:$AD$705=$A$5,ROW($AD$1:$AD705)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($AD$1:$AE$705,SMALL(IF($AD$1:$AE$705=$A$5,ROW($AD$1:$AD$705)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

This is a way to have a VLOOKUP function that gives me multiple outputs, as I have several inputs for each "date" value.
The AD1:AE705 array is pulled from another sheet using a pretty simple formula:

```
='ACTIVE'!J2
='ACTIVE'!A2&IF('ACTIVE'!R2>0,"(" &'ACTIVE'!R2&" Days)",)
```

The issue I'm coming across is that when a row is deleted from the "Active" sheet, for some reason, the dates just stop being recognized correctly. I removed the ISERROR function to test what exactly was going on and got this as an error code:
"Refrence does not exist: 8/1/21 not found"
This is strange as one look at the array shows that that date is in it. Is there a way to prevent this type of error? I've seen people using the INDIRECT function to deal with this, but I frankly don't completely understand how to integrate that into my current code

Comment: Google Sheets and Excel aren't the same. Please ensure your tags are appropriate, i.e. the program you are actually using.

Comment: Will do, but the formulas here are the same across both programs...

Comment: Certain approaches don't work in both though... for example `REGEXEXTRACT` is Sheets only. Using the appropriate tag(s) helps ensure that you get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advice

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($AD$1:$AE$705,SMALL(IF($AD$1:$AD$705=$A$5,ROW($AD$1:$AD705))
                                                                         ^
```

Can it solve if you add a dollar sign (`$AD$705`)?